# Magento 2 knockout not loading

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

i just did an update from magento 2.4.4 to magento 2.4.5 and the knockout just stopped working, everything i do in my theme that has the knockout doesn't load, like checkout, menu, login verification, someone have you been through this? can you help me?

Comment: Can you open your browser console, reload the page, and check if there is any javascript error. Sometime, just having an error in an requirejs-config.json file can prevent the whole scripts from loading